# MethodValidationInterceptor and @Validated @ModelAttribute

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, hibernate-validator

I have a Spring Boot 2 app and I want to be able to validate controller arguments with Hibernate validator - which I'm using successfully. I have all my controller annotated as `@Validated` and I'm using the validation for request parameters like so `@PathVariable @AssertUuid final String customerId` - so far so good, everything works.

But, I want to also be able to validate `@ModelAttribute` from forms.

```java
@Controller
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
@RequestMapping(path = "/customers")
@Validated
public class CustomerController
{

    private final CustomerFacade customerFacade;

    public CustomerController(
        final CustomerFacade customerFacade
    )
    {
        this.customerFacade = customerFacade;
    }

    @GetMapping("/create")
    public ModelAndView create(
        final AccessToken accessToken
    )
    {
        return new ModelAndView("customer/create")
            .addObject("customer", new CreateCustomerRequest());
    }

    @PostMapping("/create")
    public ModelAndView handleCreate(
        final AccessToken accessToken,
        @Validated @ModelAttribute("customer") final CreateCustomerRequest customerValues,
        final BindingResult validation
    ) throws 
        UserDoesNotHaveAdminAccessException
    {
        if (validation.hasErrors()) {
            return new ModelAndView("customer/create")
                .addObject("customer", customerValues);
        }

        CustomerResult newCustomer = customerFacade.createCustomer(
            accessToken,
            customerValues.getName()
        );

        return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("..."));
    }

    public static final class CreateCustomerRequest
    {

        @NotNull
        @NotBlank
        private String name;

        public CreateCustomerRequest(final String name)
        {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public CreateCustomerRequest()
        {
        }

        public String getName()
        {
            return name;
        }

    }

}
```

But this causes the `MethodValidationInterceptor` to throw `ConstraintViolationException` when I send invalid data. This would normally make sense and I want this behaviour in every other case, but in this case, as you can see, I want to use the `BindingResult` to handle the validation errors - which is neccesary when working with forms.

Is there a way I could tell Spring to not validate this particular parameter with `MethodValidationInterceptor`, because it's already validated by the binder and I want to handle it differently?

I've been digging around in the spring code and it looks like is not designed to work together. I have the some ideas how to fix this:

- remove the `@Validated` from the argument and

  - call `validator.validate()` explicitly in the controller method - ugly and dangerous (you might forget to call it)
  - create another AOP interceptor, that would find "pairs" of `@ModelAttribute` and `BindingResult` and call the validator there, forcing the validation globally

Am I going about this completely wrong? Am I missing something? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with a solution that allows me to continue working, but I don't consider this problem solved.

As I've hinted in the original question, this Aspect forces validation of the `@ModelAttribute` when it isn't annotated with `@Validated` or `@Valid`.

This means that the `ConstraintViolationException` is not thrown for invalid `@ModelAttribute` and you can handle the errors in method body.

```java
import com.google.common.collect.Iterators;
import com.google.common.collect.PeekingIterator;
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.reflect.MethodSignature;
import org.springframework.core.MethodParameter;
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

@SuppressWarnings({"checkstyle:IllegalThrows"})
@Aspect
public class ControllerModelAttributeAutoValidatingAspect
{

    private final Validator validator;

    public ControllerModelAttributeAutoValidatingAspect(
        final Validator validator
    )
    {
        this.validator = validator;
    }

    @Around("execution(public * ((@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping *)+).*(..)))")
    public Object proceed(final ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable
    {
        MethodSignature methodSignature = MethodSignature.class.cast(pjp.getSignature());
        List<MethodParameter> methodParameters = getMethodParameters(methodSignature);

        PeekingIterator<MethodParameter> parametersIterator = Iterators.peekingIterator(methodParameters.iterator());
        while (parametersIterator.hasNext()) {
            MethodParameter parameter = parametersIterator.next();
            if (!parameter.hasParameterAnnotation(ModelAttribute.class)) {
                // process only ModelAttribute arguments
                continue;
            }
            if (parameter.hasParameterAnnotation(Validated.class) || parameter.hasParameterAnnotation(Valid.class)) {
                // if the argument is annotated as validated, the binder already validated it
                continue;
            }

            MethodParameter nextParameter = parametersIterator.peek();
            if (!Errors.class.isAssignableFrom(nextParameter.getParameterType())) {
                // the Errors argument has to be right after the  ModelAttribute argument to form a pair
                continue;
            }

            Object target = pjp.getArgs()[methodParameters.indexOf(parameter)];
            Errors errors = Errors.class.cast(pjp.getArgs()[methodParameters.indexOf(nextParameter)]);
            validator.validate(target, errors);
        }

        return pjp.proceed();
    }

    private List<MethodParameter> getMethodParameters(final MethodSignature methodSignature)
    {
        return IntStream.range(0, methodSignature.getParameterNames().length)
            .mapToObj(i -> new MethodParameter(methodSignature.getMethod(), i))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

}
```

Now you can just keep using validation annotations in your controller methods as you're used to, and at the same time, the `final BindingResult validation` works as expected.

```java
@PostMapping("/create")
public ModelAndView handleCreate(
    final AccessToken accessToken,
    @ModelAttribute("customer") final CreateCustomerRequest customerValues,
    final BindingResult validation
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for sharing this solution.

I used it as inspiration and as a base for creating a more general method arguments validator that I intend to use on selected methods.

Validation is triggered for methods annotated by @Validate:

```java
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Validate {
}
```

Example:

```java
@Validate
public void testMe(BindingModel bindingModel, Errors errors) {
    if (!errors.hasErrors()) {
        // bindingModel is valid
    }
}
```

And here's the modified aspect class:

```java
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.reflect.MethodSignature;
import org.springframework.core.MethodParameter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

@Aspect
@Component
public class ValidateAspect {

    private final Validator validator;

    public ValidateAspect(Validator validator) {
        this.validator = validator;
    }

    @Around("@annotation(Validate)")
    public Object proceed(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        MethodSignature methodSignature = (MethodSignature) pjp.getSignature();
        List<MethodParameter> methodParameters = getMethodParameters(methodSignature);

        for (int i = 0; i < methodParameters.size() - 1; i++) {
            MethodParameter parameter = methodParameters.get(i);

            MethodParameter nextParameter = methodParameters.get(i + 1);
            if (!Errors.class.isAssignableFrom(nextParameter.getParameterType())) {
                // the Errors argument has to be right after the validated argument to form a pair
                continue;
            }

            Object target = pjp.getArgs()[methodParameters.indexOf(parameter)];
            Errors errors = (Errors) pjp.getArgs()[methodParameters.indexOf(nextParameter)];
            validator.validate(target, errors);
        }

        return pjp.proceed();
    }

    private static List<MethodParameter> getMethodParameters(MethodSignature methodSignature) {
        return IntStream
                .range(0, methodSignature.getParameterNames().length)
                .mapToObj(i -> new MethodParameter(methodSignature.getMethod(), i))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

The above code is tested and (so far) seems to work properly with Spring Boot 2.1.4.RELEASE